# Find specific x value with y in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array[x,y] in python like this:

```
myarr=np.array([[6,15],[5,10],[7,7],[11,7],[15,10],[13,15]])

print(np.where(myarr==15))
```

which holds x,y coordinates

For example I need to find the x values where their y is 15 which in this case will be 6 and 13.

I've tried to solve this problem with `np.where` but I cant find the answer. 
I already try this too

```
print(np.where(myarr[1]==15))
```

but it give me empty values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myarr[1] means row index 1 line. there is no 15 in row index 1 line.

find in the all rows and column index 1.

```
print ( np.where(myarr[:,1]==15) )
```

and x values are

```
print ( myarr[ np.where(myarr[:,1]==15), 0 ][0] )
```